# Can I cleanup "passphrase-ssh-key" folders in /tmp

Tags: ssh, disk-usage, tmp

I have several million files (literally) in `/tmp` like this

```
./c0ihh8nn2m0wgss4/passphrase-ssh-key
./1pavjopsw5gk80kg/passphrase-ssh-key
(...)
```

Is it okay to remove these?

Rebooting, at this time, is not an option (bear with me, please).

**Edit**

What are these files anyway? Is it possible for `ssh` (`sshd` ?) not to create them or remove them after a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a reboot isn't possible, and you don't want to delete tmp files that are potentially being used somewhere, you could run:

```
$ lsof /tmp
```

to check what processes might be actively using these files. I would feel pretty safe deleting any not in use as they would be wiped on reboot anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to delete files in /tmp since they may be in use by currently running processes or part of active connections.  Doing so probably wouldn't cause any major damage but it could disrupt the stability of the running system.

I'm sure you know that /tmp gets cleaned out on reboot.

If this isn't hyperbole, several million files in /tmp would be somewhat worrisome to me.

Comment: yes, the problem is we're in the middle of a transition and rebooting this server would cause some downtime we can't afford right now. but thanks for your help